# LibUV multi-threaded handler architecture design

Tags: c, multithreading, libuv

I'm trying to architecture the main event handling of a libuv-based application. The application is composed of one (or more) UDP receivers sharing a socket, whose job is to delegate processing incoming messages to a common worker pool.

As the protocol handled is stateful, all packets coming from any given server should always be directed to the same worker  – this constraint seem to make using LibUV built-in worker pool impossible.

The workers should be able to send themselves packets.

As such, and as I am new to LibUV, I wanted to share with you the intended architecture, in order to get feedback and best practices about it.

– Each worker run their very own LibUV loop, allowing them to send directly packets over the network. Additionally, each worker has a dedicated concurrent queue for sending it messages.

– When a packet is received, its source address is hashed to select the corresponding worker from the pool.

– The receiver created a unique async handle on the receiver loop, to act as callback when processing has finished.

– The receiver notifies the worker with an async handle that a new message is available, which wakes up the worker, that starts to process all enqueued messages.

– The worker thread calls the async handle on the receiver queue, which will cause the receiver to return the buffer to pool and free all allocated resources (as such, the pool does not need to be thread-safe).

The main questions I have would be:

– What is the overhead of creating an async handle for each received message? Is it a good design?

– Is there any built-in way to send a message to another event loop?

– Would it be better to send outgoing packets using another loop, instead of doing it right from the worker loop?

Thanks.